# use python urllib2 and regex to get similar named remote file

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to download a daily file dump from a remote file which has a the following name pattern: `somename.yyyymmdd_HHmm.zip`. `yyyymmdd` is the 4 digit year, 2 digit month and 2 digit date, HH is the 2 digit hour and the last mm is the 2 digit minute. If the file was generated today, it could be `somename.20120416_0423.zip`. The '_0423' could also be 0412', depending on whether it finished dumping at 4:23 AM or 4:12AM.

My question is, how would one use regular expression to download this file knowing what we know above? Or is there a better way?

```
import urllib2

ref = regexedFilename # this would be the (sort of) unknown file name
f = urllib2.openfile(ref)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without directory listing on the remote site that's impossible unless you want to use brute force to find out the filename.

If directory listing is available, open the directory index page, parse it e.g. using BeautifulSoup, extract the list of files and then use your regex to find one that matches the format you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can see the directory listing, and you are going to have to use a regex anyway then there is no reason to waste your time with BeautifulSoup.

```
import re
file_list = re.findall('.*?\.(\d+)_(\d+)\.zip', directory_page_text)
sorted_file_list = sorted(file_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```

This of course may have to be tweaked depending on what the actual output of the directory listing looks like.